# Find the angle between the vector and the plane spanned by the vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

The task is: what is the angle between the vector $x = (1,-2, 4)$ and the plane spanned by the vectors $e_1 = (-1, 1, -1)$ and $e_2 = (-1, -1, 1)$? The answer is $cos^{-1} (19/21)^{0.5}$.

I tried to find the normal vector of the plane, but then I use a formula with the $arcsin$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: A normal vector is the [cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation) $n=e_1\times e_2=\det\begin{pmatrix} \vec i &\vec j&\vec k\\ -1&1&-1\\-1 &-1 &1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: yes, i found n = (2; 0; 0). what shall i do after that?

Comment: Your computation of $\vec n$ is wrong: your $\vec n$ is not orthogonal to $e_1$. A correct answer is $(0,2, 2)$.

Comment: got the correct meaning of the angle. thank you!

Comment: What is "meaning of the angle"?

Comment: I understand that "meaning of the angle" is the Google translate of 
"значение угла". Unfortunately Google is wrong here: back to Russian "meaning of the angle" translates as "смысл угла", compare with "meaning of life", which is "смысл жизни".

Answer (score 0):

The normal to the plane is $$\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\1\\-1\end{matrix}\right)\times\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\-1\\1\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\2\\2\end{matrix}\right)$$

The angle between this normal and the vector $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-2\\4\end{matrix}\right)$ is given by $$\cos\theta=\frac{\left(\begin{matrix}0\\2\\-2\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-2\\4\end{matrix}\right)}{\sqrt{8}\sqrt{21}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{21}}$$

But the angle between the plane and the vector $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-2\\4\end{matrix}\right)$ is the complementary angle, so the required angle is $$\arccos\sqrt{\frac{19}{21}}$$